# Weyl group and Galois action on cubic surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-surfaces, weyl-group

Let $X$ be a smooth cubic surface over a field $k$. Denote by $\bar{k}$ the separable closure of $k$ and $\bar{X}:=X\times_{k}\bar{k}$. Then it is well know that there exists a homomorphism
$$
\phi:\text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)\rightarrow W(E_{6})
$$ defined by the action of $\text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$ on $\text{Pic}(\bar{X})$. I understand that under a lattice isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}^{7}\rightarrow \text{Pic}(\bar{X})$, the root lattice $E_{6}$ is isomorphic to $(K_{\bar{X}})^{\perp}$ (the orthogonal complement of the canonical divisor). However, I am unsure how to understand the action of Galois on $\bar{X}$ from elements of $W(E_{6})$. This is because $\text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$ is acting on $\text{Pic}(\bar{X})\cong \mathbb{Z}^{7}$ which is 7 dimensional and $W(E_{6})$ is acting on the root lattice $E_{6}$, which is 6 dimensional.

Take for example $k=\mathbb{F}_{p}$ for some prime $p$, then the image of $\text{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{F}}_{p}/\mathbb{F}_{p})$ under $\phi$ is a cyclic subgroup $G$ of $W(E_{6})$ which is isomorphic to $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{q}/\mathbb{F}_{p})$, where $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ is the minimal normal extension of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ such that all 27 lines of $\bar{X}$ are defined over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$.

The generator $g$ of $G$ corresponds to the Frobenius automorphism, $\text{Frob}_{p}\in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{q}/\mathbb{F}_{p})$. If we understand how $g$ acts on $E_{6}$, then how can we understand the action of $\text{Frob}_{p}$ on $\text{Pic}(\bar{X})$?

Comment: The Galois action leaves $K_X$ invariant and preserves the decomposition $\mathbb Z K_X \oplus K_X^{\bot}$

Comment: @user41282141 Agreed, except that this gives a decomposition of an index 3 sublattice and not the whole Picard group.

Comment: @WillSawin  If I base changed $\text{Pic}(\bar{X})$ to $\mathbb{R}$ would I get the decomposition mentioned by @user41282141? Then I assume we would get a representation $\text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)\rightarrow \text{GL}_{7}(\mathbb{R})$ which might help understand the Galois action?

Comment: @WillSawin thanks, of course this lets us compute  $g(3v) = 3g(v)$ for any $v$ which is sufficient.  H U, this is the same as the observation that $GL$ of any lattice embeds into $GL_7(\mathbb Q)$

Comment: Yes, or even to $\mathbb Q$ (as user41282141 points out). This representation would be the direct sum of the standard 6-dimensional representation with a one-dimensional representation.

Comment: @user41282141,@WillSawin I understand now! Thank you both for your help!